# Dropdown nav, com menu e submenus centralizados: que erro estou cometendo?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, submenu

Estou com um pequeno problema ao centralizar um submenu de um menu dropdown. O exemplo a seguir é bastante simples, mas ilustra bem meu problema:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu1
    <li>Menu2
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu1
            <li>Submenu2
            <li>Submenu3 com outras palavras
            <li>Submenu4
        </ul>
    <li>Menu3
</ul>
```

[Preview JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxLfbmy0/).
O que acontece é o seguinte: O submenu em vermelho (dentro do segundo UL) está centralizado ao menu parentado, **Menu2**. Porém, não sei se está correto já que precisei ajustar a posição esquerda do submenu UL (50%) e do LI (-50%).

Tudo ficou centralizado, independente do tamanho do texto dos menus, porém com um problema: o bg verde mostra que o submenu UL ainda está na "posição errada", mas somente assim eu consigo centralizar perfeitamente já que não queria estipular um width fixo (em pixels) para os submenus.

É possível centralizar tudo, inclusive o sumbenu UL?

Comment: O seu problema não é esse, mas não esqueça de fechar as tags <li>

Comment: Tranquilo, hehehe, deixei assim apenas para deixar o código mais limpo. Obrigado pelo lembrete.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre por que você está utilizando `position: absolute;` para centralizar os seus itens dentro da `<ul>`, desta forma essa `<ul>` assume o tamanho total de seus itens filhos mesmo que você posicione negativamente para esquerda, além de que o elemento `<ul>` não está posicionado dentro da sua `<li>` correspondente.

A estrutura correta ficaria assim:

CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#menu > li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: orange;
}

ul#menu > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

ul#menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

ul#menu ul li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: none;
    background: tomato;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu1</li>
    <li>Menu2
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu1</li>
            <li>Submenu2</li>
            <li>Submenu3 com outras palavras</li>
            <li>Submenu4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão, mas acredito que minha pergunta não foi entendida corretamente. O que preciso é centralizar tudo: menu principal e submenus — exatamente como nesse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/vxLfbmy0/ . Acontece que no exemplo que você citou o submenu está alinhado a esquerda do menu correspondente. Note que se eu aumentar o tamanho do texto o submenu cresce para a direita e não centralizado, como eu preciso. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.